# Cloudflare Workers not respecting Caching Origin Headers

Tags: browser-cache, cloudflare

I've written a Cloudflare Worker which uses Cloudflare Images.

By default, Cloudflare Workers are sending "14400" as a *Max-age* value for caching purpose. I'd like to use "31536000" (365d) instead, to match with my origin's configuration.

I read Cloudflare's doc, various community posts about this issue, as well as some StackOverflow posts and tried these 3 solutions:

1. Changing the default Browser TTL from 4 hours (14400) to "Respect Origin Headers" in Cloudflare.

   **Tried this, the "14400" disappeared and became "0"**
2. Overriding the Browser TTL, directly in the CF Worker:

   `options.cacheControl = { browserTTL: 31536000 }`

   **Tried this, no impact**
3. Overriding the Edge TTL as well, directly in the CF Worker:

   `options.cacheControl = { browserTTL: 31536000, edgeTTL: 31536000 }`

   **Tried this, no impact**

I triple-checked our origin server, and it is returning valid cache control headers:

```
expires: Tue, 16 May 2023 18:45:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: public
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Cloudflare Workers are sending "14400" as a Max-age value for caching purpose"? Where are you seeing this? Workers doesn't modify caching headers.

Comment: @KentonVarda You can either use Developer tools (Network tab), cURL or 3rd party tools to check Response headers. By default Cloudflare's Browser TTL configuration is "4 hours" (14,400s). You can override this setting for everything except CF Workers.

Comment: Are you saying you are seeing the "Browser cache TTL" setting is not having any effect when the request goes to Workers? Are the workers URL and your origin URL both under your same zone, where you have disabled "Browser cache TTL"?

Answer (score 0):

After having Cloudflare's support investigating this issue, our Cloudflare worker is finally taking into consideration our Origin cache headers.

We did not make any changes, so this issue was most likely due to the time necessary for changes to propagate.